# Trigger Bootstrap modal on dynamically added data-toggle element

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm dynamically creating and adding the following to the DOM:

```
<a href="my_modal_link" data-toggle="modal">Click me</a>
```

However, since this content is added dynamically after the page is loaded, the Bootstrap modal is never registered, and clicking the link navigates the browser to the new page rather than displaying it as a modal dialog.

How can I get Bootstrap to know about this dynamically added modal tag so that it will display the content in a modal when the link is clicked?  Or, do I have to manually wire up the click event to call .modal()?

Comment: The answer is yes u have to bind the click event

Answer (score 1):

As you're creating dynamically the links, you have to use event handlers, something like this

**HTML**

```
<a href="#my_modal1" class="modal_links" data-toggle="modal">Click me # 1</a>
<a href="#my_modal2" class="modal_links" data-toggle="modal">Click me # 2</a>
<a href="#my_modal3" class="modal_links" data-toggle="modal">Click me # 3</a>
....
<a href="#my_modalN" class="modal_links" data-toggle="modal">Click me # N</a>
```

**JS**

```
jQuery(function($){
    $("body").on("click",".modal_links",function(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();
        var modalToOpen = $(this).attr("href");
        $(modalToOpen).modal('show'); // also you can use "toggle" instead of "show"
    });
});
```